# Smiling aliens seal off a city and observe the humans there?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, alien-invasion

I believe the aliens look like tall humanoids and they have fixed smiles on their faces (or perhaps masks). Then someone attacks an alien at some point, cracking its mask/face. The aliens aren't aggressive but they clearly view humans as lesser creatures, like pets.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question could use some more details; check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they can help you recall any additional details to [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you read this?